# Getting an "not configured as an allowed type for this instance of ObjectSerializer" serialization error

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm working on an integration project. I get an error while inserting the entity to the mongodb.

The error message return this string below :

> **MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: 'An error occurred while serializing the OrderData property of class Order: Type MarketplaceOrder is not configured as an allowed type for this instance of ObjectSerializer.**'

A few steps before, I'm getting data from any api resources and converting the data to my generic object `<T>` like below line.

```
var data = (JArray)returnDataFromNetwork.Data;
var order = data.ToObject<T>()
```

I get the error while inserting the entity to the mongodb

```
_orderRepository.InsertAsync(new Order
  {
    OrderData = order,
  });
```

```
public class Order
{
  public object OrderData { get; set; }
}

public class MarketplaceOrder
{
  [JsonProperty("marketplace")]
  public string Marketplace { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("account_id")]
  public int AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your support,

The all the things which I try to explain is on "hangfire" (background service) project. First I get this error message on server console. Then I tried to debug locally to understand where the issue is. I could not understand the error message detail.

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/bson/mapping/

Comment: hi @fredrik, thanks for reply. It's a bit hard to understand where to start this mapping and which classes should map and how ?

Answer (score 28):

I think you use 2.19 .net driver. See release [notes](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases/tag/v2.19.0) with the description of your issue.

> The ObjectSerializer has been changed to only allow deserialization of types that are considered safe.
> What types are considered safe is determined by a new configurable AllowedTypes function (of type Func<Type, bool>).
> The default AllowedTypes function is ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes which returns true for a number of well-known framework types that we have deemed safe.
> A typical example might be to allow all the default allowed types as well as your own types. This could be accomplished as follows:

The solution:

> var objectSerializer = new ObjectSerializer(type => ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes(type) || type.FullName.StartsWith("MyNamespace"));
> BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(objectSerializer);

Comment: Quick note, don't you think this is a breaking change ? Tagging the new version 2.19 seems weird to me

Comment: thats super breaking....  :- (

Comment: Where in the code does this go?

Comment: it's static configuration and should be placed before any mongo queries usage

Comment: The JIRA ticket for this. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4581

Comment: This is about as breaking as a piece of functionality can get.  Making serialization changes of this scope woud have massive implications for existing users.

@Markus ,you can add that code to a startup.cs / program.cs method or even as a static method call in the class which is doing the bson serialization attempt.  Either appear to work.
You simply need to call the above blob of code prior to attempting the serialization into  / out of mongodb via the driver.

Answer (score 6):

To add to the answer of `dododo`.
The following fix may not work for you in 100% of the cases:

```cs
var objectSerializer = new ObjectSerializer(type => ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes(type) || type.FullName.StartsWith("MyNamespace"));
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(objectSerializer);
```

The problem arises when you want to serialize a generic collection that has your custom type as a generic argument. For example, `List<MyType>`. Here is why:

1. `ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes(type)` is `false`. `List<>` is considered as allowed by default. But it will also [validate](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/fdd2ba5270a3547fcd2ab8ad5a558d5f7e4f26fd/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/ObjectSerializer.cs#L580) generic argument which is `MyType` and it's not allowed by default.
2. `type.FullName.StartsWith("MyNamespace")` is also `false` as the type's full name starts with `System.Collections.Generic.List`.

#### Solution 1

Extend custom validation to check generic type arguments:

```cs
private static bool IsAllowedType(Type type)
{
    return type.IsConstructedGenericType ? 
        type.GetGenericArguments().All(IsAllowedType) :
        type.FullName.StartsWith("MyNamespace");
}

var objectSerializer = new ObjectSerializer(type => ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes(type) || IsAllowedType(type));
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(objectSerializer);
```

#### Solution 2

Allow all types:

```cs
var objectSerializer = new ObjectSerializer(ObjectSerializer.AllAllowedTypes);
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(objectSerializer);
```